# add search bar function to embedded google html map

Tags: google-maps

I created a map using the new Google Maps and I am using the "embed this to my site" feature, but it has no search bar.  The intent of the map is to enter an address to see if you fall within a boundary I created but I don't know how to alter the HTML code to add a search feature.  I also have next to no HTML experience, so please be kind.

Here is what I have as the embed code:

No actual space between first < and iframe but I added it for it to show up

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=z-3d_xUUkSNQ.kL7YAhEFIavc" width="640" height="480">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do. One idea is you can use the address provided by your users to obtain the coordinate of the location. This can be done via [**google Geocoding service**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Then from there you can determine if the given address falls within the region you have provided. You probably want to start playing around with HTML and Javascript first for a more complicated task like this.